# upload image to web service from database using xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to upload a image from phone to web service my link is like below as sample
"http://sample.com/upload_image.php"
my code is as below for post:

```
-(IBAction) post:(id) sender
{
    count = 0;
    self.progress = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];

    self.progress.center = self.view.center; 
    progress.hidden = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.progress];
    nmyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateUI:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    NSString *filename = [NSString alloc];
    filename = [self randomStringWithLength:5];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 100);
    NSError *error;
    NSData *searchData;
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response;

    // setting up the URL to post to
    NSString *urlString = @"http://dev9.edisbest.com/upload_image.php";

    // setting up the request object now

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     add some header info now
     we always need a boundary when we post a file
     also we need to set the content type

     You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
     as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
     */
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the post
     */

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n",filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    searchData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",response);
    NSString *imageName;
    imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:searchData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"retrun Result of Upload Photo.. %@",imageName);

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]                            completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) 
    {                                NSLog(@"Finished with status code: %i", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);  }];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    ///self.returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);

   }
```

when i build and run i will be asked to choose image and when i select an image to upload

I got a message as the following

```
**[Switching to process 553 thread 0x4e03]
2015-04-28 12:08:12.856 image-video-upload[553:207] (null)
2015-04-28 12:08:12.857 image-video-upload[553:207] retrun Result of Upload Photo.. 
2015-04-28 12:08:12.889 image-video-upload[553:207] Finished with status code: 0**
```

Above message shown in my console and crashed

Comment: firstly you need to Create  UIImage From URL then convert image  into base 64 encoding and store  it into dictionary and send it to web service...

Comment: Read my comment carefully...

Comment: can u please post me a sample program to upload image in webservice please it will help me to learn correctly

Comment: I don't have code now.. but will try and inform you.. k

Comment: @gopinath i have posted my answer ... just change the key which used in user JSON and Your url.  and header fields are optional . no need to set it. but i have set in my example but it is optional.

Comment: @gopinath have you tried my answer or not. replay me.

Comment: hi for late reply  sorry i am  learning and trying but i need a  webservice newly because i think the service i am using is expired :(

Comment: k.. If you are satisfied with my answer please accept it.

Comment: @gopinath Thanks.. can you upvote for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"i3.png"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);


NSString *encodedString = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionnary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[dictionnary setObject:encodedString forKey:@"imageData"];


NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionnary
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                     error:&error];

NSString *urlString = @"http://Your url";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// Prepare the request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Data-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[jsonData length]]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

NSError *errorReturned = nil;
NSURLResponse *theResponse =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                     returningResponse:&theResponse
                                                 error:&errorReturned];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code from my project to upload image
// create request

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];                                    
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// set Content-Type in HTTP header
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

// post body
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

// add params (all params are strings)
for (NSString *param in _params) {
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

// add image data
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:imageData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// setting the body of the post to the reqeust
[request setHTTPBody:body];

 // set the content-length
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

  // set URL
  [request setURL:requestURL];
```

Comment: for (NSString *param in _params) {
     [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

Comment: please explain this i am getting error as undeclared identifier.Ifi declare _params as string it shows warning as "collection expression type NSString maynot respond to 'count By enumerating With State::object count" please explain and while running it during uploadingit gets Run paused

Comment: whats the exact issue.?

Comment: i cant upload image to webservice while i am uploading it gets paused my mail id 1990gopinath@gmail.com please contact me or send any project regarding to this ..

Comment: check this tutorial plz,,
it will resolve your problem.
http://www.itworld.com/article/2702129/development/how-to-upload-photos-from-ios-to-a-rest-api.html

Comment: sorry for late reply i am waiting for the web service link!! i will update once i get link!!!